# Disable `semantics` system in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am encountering [a bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68276) of Flutter semantics system. Since I do not have any clue about how to solve that, I may have to disable the semantics system temporarily until that is fixed (sorry for disabled people :/).

Thus, I wonder *how to disable semantics system* in Flutter? I do not see any flag that can control this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to stop this I wrap the widget in return
ExcludeSemantics()

Its a bug on the flutter platform talked about here:

[flutter/flutter#37886](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37886)

[flutter/flutter#30675](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30675)

Comment: Thanks! Wrapping app with `ExcludeSemantics` works for me :)

Comment: By the way, I am a little bit confused about the two links you provide. How is it related to question?